# SQLAlchemy ORM NOT EXISTS: table alias scoping

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have three entities, `A`, `B`, `C`, where `C` links `A`s to `B`s (`A-*C-B`).  I want to find those instances of `A` for which there is no instance of `C` that is not connected to a `B`.

I haven't been able to come up with a SQLAlchemy query that will do this for me and I'm beginning to think there's a problem with the compiler.

The following unit test illustrates this:

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, literal

_sql_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
session = sessionmaker(bind=_sql_engine)()

def test_model():
    Base = declarative_base()

    class A(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'a'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    class B(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'b'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    class C(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'c'
        a = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        b = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


    Base.metadata.create_all(_sql_engine)

    a = [A(id=10),      A(id=20)]
    c = [C(a=10, b=11), C(a=20, b=21)]
    b = [B(id=11)]

    session.add_all(a + c + b)
    session.commit()

    q = session.query(A).filter(
        A.id < literal(100),
        ~(
            session.query(C)
                .filter(
                A.id == C.a,
                ~(
                    session.query(B)
                    .filter(
                        B.id == C.b,
                    ).exists()
                )
            ).exists()
        )
    )

    print(q.statement)
    print(len(q.all()))

    assert len(q.all()) == 1
```

The test expects one result, but it gets zero.  The SQL statement that is printed is

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM a 
WHERE a.id < :param_1 AND NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM c 
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
FROM b, a 
WHERE b.id = c.b AND a.id = c.a))))
```

Now, it looks to me like the problem is with the third `FROM` statement.  `b` and `a` override the aliases above and disconnected from the previous constraints.

Is this correct?  Is this how scoping in SQL works?  If so, am I making a mistake with SQLAlchemy or is this a bug?

(The unit test uses SQLite, but the end result should run in PostgreSQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to zzzeek on github, I found the answer: aliases are shadowed in subqueries after the second nesting.  If we don't want this, we use [correlated subqueries](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#correlated-subqueries).

Fixed unit test:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, aliased
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, create_engine, literal

_sql_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
session = sessionmaker(bind=_sql_engine)()


def test_model():
    Base = declarative_base()

    class A(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'a'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    class B(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'b'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    class C(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'c'
        a = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        b = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


    Base.metadata.create_all(_sql_engine)

    a = [A(id=10),      A(id=20)]
    c = [C(a=10, b=11), C(a=20, b=21)]
    b = [B(id=11)]

    session.add_all(a + c + b)
    session.commit()

    q = session.query(A).filter(
        A.id < literal(100),
        ~(
            session.query(C)
                .filter(
                A.id == C.a,
                ~(
                    session.query(B)
                    .filter(
                        B.id == C.b
                    ).exists().correlate(A,C)
                )
            ).exists()
        )
    )

    print(q.statement)
    print(len(q.all()))

    assert len(q.all()) == 1
```